# where is "Outlook: "Create new mail" -> to: (Email address cache)?" stored in

Tags: email, exchange, outlook

I changed a laptop in an Active Directory Environment. 
Because the Userprofile got really big in the last past years, I decided to create a new Profile. I did the following Tasks.

- deattached his Exchange Mailbox in
  System Manager
- renamed the User to x-old
- created a new user with same
  privileged etc.. (acctually i copied
  the old one.)
- attached the mailbox to the new user.
- logged in with new user and copied
  some files from the old profile..

When the User starts outlook, everything works fine except the "email address history" is missing. You know that completion when you create a new mail and type into the "TO:" field for eg. an "a" it gives you a couple of suggestions like "amail@..", "amessage@..".

Where are these informations stored in?

Which file do i have to backup from the old profile?

Comment: I've wondered the same thing before. Someone told me once too, but I can't remember where it was and it wasn't in an Active Directory or Exchange environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The files you are looking for are at **%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook** and they have the extension **NK2**.

References and to a few tools for managing the nickname cache.

- http://www.slipstick.com/emo/2005/up050609.htm#nk2
- http://www.slipstick.com/problems/nicknamecache.asp

Comment: perfect answer!

Answer (score 2):

It is stored here... c::\Documents and Settings\"username"\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook

close outlook, copy the file under the above path to the new profile(same path). Relaunch Outlook. Worked for me in the past.

Comment: ah ok, that's what i suspected. Will try that today.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the personnal address book of the user?

Comment: I think those entrys are fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find/store outlook express inbox sent items etc or copy and paste from another PC ... below is where the files are kept... they have the .dbx extension i.e. "Sent Items.dbx"

C:\Documents and Settings\"user"\Local Settings\Application Data\Identities{"your ID number string"}\Microsoft\Outlook Express.

*This is using XP and outlook express 6

Tip - some folders may be hidden.. Make sure you enable to view hidden folders!